# Selenium IDE - Assert color of a test

Tags: css, selenium, selenium-ide

I've been trying all the solutions i've found on StackO, but none of them works for me.

How would you verify that the backgound color is indeed blue for this element
css=#box10 > div:nth-child(3)
on this page https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors.asp

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried something but did not worked on Selenium IDE, but worked in Console:

1. You should get the color of the box with id="box10"

   Return getComputedStyle(document.querySelector("#box10")).backgroundColor
2. You should take the string from the a.innerText inside the box with id="box10"

3.Compare the values

But here comes the catch:
*assert on background.color with value ${box.color.a} Failed:
Actual value 'rgb(0, 0, 255)' did not match '#0000ff'*

getComputedStyle(document.querySelector("#box10")).backgroundColor will return the rgb value
I have tried to convert it with the code found :

```
const rgb2hex = (rgb) => `#${rgb.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/).slice(1).map(n => parseInt(n, 10).toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join('')}`; rgb2hex(getComputedStyle(document.querySelector("#box10")).backgroundColor)
```

and it works in console, but it doesn`t work on Selenium IDE Execute script command; I don`t have much more time to investigate, but i hope is a good starting point. Let me know if you found something!

[IDE:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08zXb.png)